# Continuous Integration (Hudson/Jenkins) and R Programming

Tags: unit-testing, r, continuous-integration, hudson, jenkins

Does anyone know of a way to do continuous integration with R programming?  I'm aware of tools like the svUnit package to do the unit tests, but has anyone tried to run these with Hudson/Jenkins?

Comment: +1 I am interested in this as well, in order to automatically catch package updates from CRAN that break my tests.  I wish I could easily send a bunch of tests upstream, to assist package developers, but automating tests will do for now.

Comment: just wondering whether @Iterator or Travis tried out the latest svUnit. according to me svUnit offers '''very good''' integration in Jenkins, so seeing Dirks answer being "accepted" makes me think you have not yet taken advance of it.

Comment: @mariotomo - Thanks for the alert - I'll definitely check it out.  I have an upcoming project that will need to use such testing.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I do not see any particular problem.  These things tend to be *scripted* so could just

- point to the top of your repository
- *N* minutes after each checkin, loop over source directories
- invoke `R CMD check` on each
- your package has to be set to use unit test, for which you can use

  - [RUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/package=RUnit) which is the initial unit testing for R ; it is widely used
  - [testthat](http://cran.r-project.org/package=testthat) which is a newer package by Hadley, and used by many of his packages
  - [svUnit](http://cran.r-project.org/package=svUnit) by Philippe which AFAIK never caught on quite as much as the other two.

That is really not any different from continuous integration with compiled languages.   Your question is really about how to do unit testing within R, and that question has been covered before.

Comment: what you write is quite true —in general—, the question however explicitly mentions Jenkins/Hudson, and to my knowledge the best integration is offered by [svUnit](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/svUnit/R/?root=sciviews). see my other answer. ... IMO, just being able to execute scripted unit testing isn't of much use if the results are not in a format compatible with the chosen continuous integration tool.

Comment: Any suggestions on getting Jenkins to show a build has failed if R CMD check fails?

Comment: Sure, look at the newish [r-travis project on github](https://github.com/craigcitro/r-travis) which has a `dump_logs` function.

Comment: what do you mean by "fail"? that it fails running or that it runs successfully and identifies errors, failures or skipped tests?

Answer (score 5):

at office we have been using Hudson/Jenkins for quite a while. I have contributed [integration of svUnit to Jenkins](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/svUnit/R/?root=sciviews) so I would strongly advise you to use svUnit before trying anything else.

have a look at the two libraries I maintain: [logging](http://logging.r-forge.r-project.org/) and [delftfews](http://delftfews.r-forge.r-project.org/) or at myself trying to follow [zoo](http://r-forge.r-project.org/projects/zoo/) and [redistribute it on github](http://github.com/mfrasca/zoo).

I have not been doing housekeeping recently so the three scripts (in [zoo](https://github.com/mfrasca/zoo/blob/master/pkg/zoo/tests/doRUnit.R), [logging](https://github.com/mfrasca/r-logging/blob/master/pkg/tests/doSvUnit.R), [delftfews](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/pkg/tests/doSvUnit.R?view=markup&revision=HEAD&root=delftfews)) are all slightly different. the one in my zoo version will stop if any test fails. this is practical when you are running `R CMD check`, but probably less of a good idea when doing continuous integration.

Comment: can you clarify how to trigger Jenkins to fail, or where in the svUnit code it is mentioned? I could not find any relevant text in the svUnit package documentation or vignette, and it is not clear to me from the scripts you wrote (I am new to CI) what will trigger Jenkins to pass/fail. Does it just respond to stderr?

Comment: you say you're new to CI, I suggest you read Jenkin's manual in order to understand its structure, maybe you want to have a look at a working Jenkins server? (e.g.: https://csvjdbc.ci.cloudbees.com/job/csvjdbc/) any committed change in your sources will trigger Jenkins to run whatever script you register, and on successful completion of the script, it will use the generated report to publish the succeeding/failing/skipped tests.

Comment: How did you set up the succeeding/failing, based on the report? Is that standard in Jenkins?

Comment: @bobK - I examined the code of Jenkins and JUnit4 to see what JUnit4 produces and what Jenkins understands. so on one side I had svUnit (which I needed to play the same role as JUnit4), with its internal representation of success/failure/skip/error, on the other hand Jenkins and in the middle, as a connecting arc, the (not particularly well documented) xml structure used by JUnit4, understood by Jenkins. or did I misunderstand your question?

Answer (score 1):

Hudson/Jenkins supports running bash scripts. I think that you can use this as an entrance to your R world. In R, a simple way to keep result is to use sink("toYourFile.txt") and then use CI's result display function to show the toYourFile.txt.

Comment: It is easy to get the CI to show the file, how do you get it to identify errors?

Comment: "how to identify errors?", you need the output to be in a format that can be recognized by Jenkins, and this is exactly what you can do with svUnit, using the "junit" protocol.